# getRange variable range

Tags: google-sheets, ranking

I am trying to use a google sheet to rank a list of elements. This list is continually updated, so it can be troublesome to update the list if i already have hundreds of elements ranked and need to rank 10 new ones. Rather than having to re-rank some of the previously ranked elements every time (whether manually or using formulas), i thought it easier to write a macro that would re-rank for me.

1 - element A

2 - element B

3 - element C

new element: element D

For instance if i wanted element D to be ranked 2nd, i would need to change element B to 3 and element C to 4. This is tedious when doing hundreds of elements.

Here is my code so far but I get stuck with the getRange lines. Rankings are in column A.

```
 function RankElements() { 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var v1 = r.getValue();
  var v2 = v1 + 1 
  var v3 = v2 + 1
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();
  s.getRange(1,v2).setValue(v2);
  s.getRange(1,v3).autoFill(s.getRange(1,v3+":"+1,lastRow), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  s.getRange(1,v3+":"+1,lastRow).copyTo(s.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  s.getFilter().sort(1, true);
};
```

Comment: According to what should the elements be ranked? How is the list updated, manually by a user? Could you please share a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on, as well as the outcome you expect?

Comment: Ranked in column A based on user preference. Updated manually by the user, would input rank of newly added rows/elements then run the script/macro to update the rest of the list and resort. Here is a dummy sheet I made.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T5mcwl_aDIDWDN1Td4Gd9sOyv7mM_j6xu7zcXdVXHnI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Can you make this file public? At least with view-access.

Comment: Oh sorry, just made it public

Comment: Thank you. From what I understand, you want to add new rows manually and then fire the function to update the rest of the list. In this case, how would you specify which elements you just added (and their ranking should not change) and which were there before (and their ranking should be updated)? I'm thinking here of several possibilities: (1) triggering this with an `onEdit`, and (2) using script properties for the script to tell the new elements apart from the old ones. What do you think of this? What would be more appropriate to your situation?

Comment: Good question. "New" elements WILL NOT have a value in column A and "existing" elements WILL have a value in column A. When i add new elements to the spreadsheet, I will add them to the bottom, but if time has passed and i have added several new elements since the last time the user has updated their rankings, naturally the list will get longer. Also there is the chance that the list may have been sorted by a different column so the order could be different than "existing elements on top, new elements on bottom" i.e. it could all be mixed together.

Comment: I would think sticking with empty in column A = new and a value in column A = existing would be enough, and the idea behind my code i provided was: user puts a ranking value in column A for one of the "new" elements, then with that cell still highlighted, runs the script. Then the script says "highlighted cell = x rank, so ill see if any existing elements have that rank already, if they do, make that cell x+1 and everything below that rank is incremented by 1 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Iterate through all values in column A.
- For each value, check if (1) ranking is equal or below the new one, and (2) it's not the element that is being added.
- If both these conditions are met, add `1` to the current ranking.

It could be something like this:

```js
function RankElements() { 
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  const row = cell.getRow();
  const newRanking = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
  const firstRow = 2;
  const columnA = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues()
                       .map(row => row[0]); // Retrieve column A values
  for (let i = 0; i < columnA.length; i++) { // Iterate through column A values
    if (columnA[i] >= newRanking && (i + firstRow) != row) {
      sheet.getRange(firstRow + i, 1).setValue(columnA[i] + 1); // Add 1 to ranking
    }
  }
  sheet.getFilter().sort(1, true);
};
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.